# Switch to new window only if it opens in new window and verify whether page is loaded properly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click all links in drop down. Some links will open a new browser window where some link will be loaded in the same page.

So, I want to switch to new window only whenever new window is opened and also need to confirm whether the new page is loaded properly.
 I have already code to switch windows. But its trying to switch new window even though new window is not opened.

Could someone help me here.

Below is the relevant piece of HTML:

```
<html>
    <div class="column span-8">
        <div class="search-container align-center">
            <div class="search">
                <div class="search-dropdown" onclick="showHideUtilMenu(event, 'SearchMenu');">
                    <span id="searchoptionValue">Consumer</span>
                    <span id="dropdownarrow"</span>
                    <span id="searchurlValue" style="display: none;">http://</span>
                    <div id="SearchMenu" class="utility-menu combobox visible">
                        <ul class="menu-list">
                            <li class="menu-link">
                                <li class="menu-link divider">
                                    <a onclick="getSearchOption('Consumer','http://');">Consumer</a>
                                ...
```

Here is the code that I have used so far:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-dropdown']/div[1]/ul/li"));
for (WebElement option : list)
{
    String strLabel = option.getText();
    if(strlabel.equalsIgnoreCase(value1) && country.equals("US"))
    {
        option.findElement(By.linkText(strLabel)).click();
        CommonFunctions.waitForPageLoad();
        CommonFunctions.switchWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the web-page that you are trying to control, or at least the relevant piece of HTML?

Comment: <html><div class="column span-8">
<div class="search-container align-center">
<div class="search">
<div class="search-dropdown" onclick="showHideUtilMenu(event, 'SearchMenu');">
<span id="searchoptionValue">Consumer</span>
<span id="dropdownarrow"/>
<span id="searchurlValue" style="display: none;">http://</span>
<div id="SearchMenu" class="utility-menu combobox visible">
<ul class="menu-list">
<li class="menu-link">
<li class="menu-link divider">
<a onclick="getSearchOption('Consumer','http://');">Consumer</a>
code:

Comment: Code Snippet:List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-dropdown']/div[1]/ul/li"));     
for (WebElement option : list) {
String strLabel = option.getText();
if(strlabel.equalsIgnoreCase(value1) && country.equals("US"))
{
option.findElement(By.linkText(strLabel)).click();  
click();
CommonFunctions.waitForPageLoad();
CommonFunctions.switchWindow();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need methods something like below

```
class CommonFunctions {
   /**
   * It will wait for an element until it loads completely
   */
  public static void waitForPageToLoad() {
        int i=0;
    while(isElementPresent(By.id("<specifySomeLocator>")))
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if(++i>500)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  /**
   * It will Switch the control to new window if exist.
   */
  public static boolean switchToWindow(String mainWindowHandle) {
     Set<String> windowhandles=driver.getWindowhandles();
     if(windowhandles.size()>1) {
        windowhandles.remove(mainWindowHandle);
        driver.switchTo().window((String)windowhandles.toArray()[0]);
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
  }

}
```

And you try to implement your code something like below

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-dropdown']/div[1]/ul/li"));
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    String strLabel = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-dropdown']/div[1]/ul/li")).get(i).getText();
    if(strlabel.equalsIgnoreCase(value1) && country.equals("US"))
    {
        String mainWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
        option.findElement(By.linkText(strLabel)).click();
        CommonFunctions.waitForPageToLoad();
        if(CommonFunctions.switchToWindow(mainWindowHandle)){
           //do your operation in new window
           //close new window using ==> driver.close();
           //switch back to main window ==> driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
        } else {
           //do your operations in main window itself
        }
    }
}
```

FYI : If you iterate list of WebElements like below, it will throw [StaleElementReferenceException](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) while trying access second element in that list if page reloads while doing other operations with first element.

```
for (WebElement option : list)
{
    String strLabel = option.getText();
    //do some operations
}
```

For isElementPresent Method implementation click [here](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.com/2012/07/iselementpresent.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a general advice, rather than a direct answer to your question.

You can navigate from the current web-page to another web-page, using any of the following options:

```
driver.get(...);
driver.navigate().to(...);
driver.switchTo().frame(...);
driver.switchTo().window(...);
```

However, once you do that, any of the elements that you have obtained from the DOM of the previous web-page, may become "stale".

In order to avoid this, it is recommended that you first obtain all the URLs (strings) that you want to go to, and navigate to each one of them **only** afterwards.

Taking the code in your question as an example, you can change it as follows:

```
List<String> strLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-dropdown']/div[1]/ul/li"));
for (WebElement option : list)
{
    String strLabel = option.getText();
    if (strlabel.equalsIgnoreCase(value1) && country.equals("US"))
        strLabels.add(strLabel);
}
for (String strLabel : strLabels)
{
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(strLabel)).click();
    CommonFunctions.waitForPageLoad();
    CommonFunctions.switchWindow();
}
```